# @Nullable Eclipse Analysis not working properly

Tags: java, eclipse

I find it quite handy to use the @Nullable and @Nonnull Annotations for Parameters and return values.

However the Eclipse Analysis seems a bit patchy. I find the follwing case to be really annoying:

```
public class SomeEntity {
  private SomeObj someObj;

  public void setSomeObj(@Nullable SomeObj someObj) {
    this.someObj = someObj;
  }

  @Nullable public SomeObj getSomeObj() {
    return someObj;
  }

  public boolean hasNewSomeObj() {
    return someObj != null;
  }
}
```

Now when I make the following call it gives me the following Eclipse warning as an error:
"Potential null pointer access: The method getZuordnenMitDatenuebernahme() may return null"

```
if(someEntity.hasNewSomeObj()) {
  someOperator.doStuff(someEntity.getSomeObj().getSomething());
}
```

Even so the Null check is covered by the prior method call.

Does anyone have any good suggestions on how to deal with this? I would really like to keep my annotations on the return values.

Eclipse: Juno Release 1

Java: 1.6

jsr305 implementation: com.google.findbugs.jsr305 2.0.1

Comment: Is this Java 7 or Java 8 (there are changes in the way Eclipse handles these for Java 8)?

Comment: All you can do is use the `getSomeObj` method and test for null.

Comment: That would be a shame, this case has been dumbed down quite a bit. There are other cases that are bit more complex.

Comment: Did you consider using Java 8 `Optional`? - I updated my answer with some example code for this approach.

Comment: Sadly Java 8 is not an option for our client... but I do like the approach.

Answer (score 2):

Actually @thr0wable provided a good answer.

It is not possible for the Eclipse compiler to guarantee, that `someEntity.getSomeObj()` will not return null after `someEntity.hasNewSomeObj()` was called, because multiple threads may access and modify `someEntity` at any time.

For the same reason the following code will also produce a compile time error for good reason:

```
if(someEntity.getSomeObj() != null) {
    someOperator.doStuff(someEntity.getSomeObj().getSomething());
}
```

The only way to guarantee, that the object is actually not null, is by doing the following:

```
SomeObj o = someEntity.getSomeObj();
if(o != null) {
    someOperator.doStuff(o.getSomething());
}
```

**UPDATE**

With Java 8, you should consider using [Optional](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html), which provides exactly the functionality you need:

```
static class SomeEntity {
    private Optional<Object> someObj;

    public void setSomeObj(Object someObj) {
        this.someObj = Optional.ofNullable(someObj);
    }

    public Optional<Object> getSomeObj() {
        return someObj;
    }
}
```

Then your example code could be simplified to this, when using a lambda expression:

```
someEntity.getSomeObj().ifPresent(o -> System.out.println(o));
```

I'm not sure, if the compile time checks are already implemented in the latest JDT Java 8 build, but once it gets released, I think you should certainly get compile time warnings/errors, if you try to access an `Optional` Object by `Optional#get()` without first checking `Optional#isPresent()`.

Answer (score 1):

In

```
if(someEntity.hasNewSomeObj()) {
  someOperator.doStuff(someEntity.getSomeObj().getSomething());
}
```

The call to `someEntity.getSomeObj()` may still return `null` as you declare `@Nullable`, so calling `getSomething()` then will result in a NPE.

Comment: How can getSomeObj() return null if someEntity.hanNewSomeObj() returns true?

Comment: I don't know the exact code, but if this runs multithreaded a second thread can call `someEntity.setSomeObj(null)` right between `if(someEntity.hasNewSomeObj())` and `someEntity.getSomeObj().getSomething()`.

Comment: Fair enough, however I haven't asked about multi-threading. It is just an example of how the @Nullable/@Nonnull Annoations are not evaluated properly, since a simple null check makes the error marker go away.